# xdebug issue with IIS and php 5.2

Tags: php, xdebug, iis-8

I have searched for this question so far no success...

I am using php 5.2 (IDE:netbean) with IIS 8 as web server. I installed php_xdebug-2.2.2-5.2-vc9-nts xdebug. 
Here is my php.ini changes:

```
zend_extension="C:\php\php_xdebug-2.2.2-5.2-vc9-nts.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
; Port number must match debugger port number in NetBeans IDE Tools > Options > PHP
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

then I restarted IIS; but when I copy paste html of phpinfo() in xdebug wizard I got below:

```
Summary
Xdebug installed: no
Server API: CGI/FastCGI
Windows: yes - Compiler: MS VC9 - Architecture: x86
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 5.2.17
Zend API nr: 220060519
PHP API nr: 20060613
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: no
Configuration File Path: C:\WINDOWS
Configuration File: C:\PHP\php.ini
Extensions directory: .
Instructions

Download
Move the downloaded file to .
Edit C:\PHP\php.ini and add the line
zend_extension = .\
Restart the webserver
```

it seems that xdebug was not installed successfully. any idea?

Comment: What i finally did: installed php 5.4 and used xdebug new version with netbeans. it is working now!!!